# Backup to Amazon Cloud drive

Tags: backup, cloud, duplicity, borgbackup

Amazon Cloud Drive (acd) offers "unlimited" storage for a very affordable price.
I wonder, if there are any backup solutions under linux that are usable with it.

I am aware of acd_cli. With this it is possible to mount acd to a folder, so that in theory any linux backups software can be used.

But there are some limitations, due to the (compared to a HDD) slow data-rate. Thus, reading from the backup must be avoided/limited. Furthermore, the backup must be robust to interruptions and continue where it was stopped.

Last but not least, the backup must be encrypted.

I have tested duplicity/duply, but I have not yet managed to get one full backup finished (does it even continue an interrupted backup, or does it start over from scratch?)

Also, I have done some research about borg backup, but the developers do discurage using acd.

I'd be interested in other proposals and your experience with it.

Regards,
Hendrik

Comment: Does s3ql work with this backend storage system? It works nicely with S3

Answer (score 0):

I am searching also and testing.

Duplicati 2.0 works, I was able to backup 2 Go of files with encryption and to restore them from ACD. Note that it is still in development process.

However using HUBIC as backend I got 2 files not backuped (or lost) and 2 others corrupted. I am still struggling with Duplicati user documentation/users forums to set up correctly Duplicati in order to get alarm on such data loss or corruption (whatever they occur during backuping or later), if not automatic detection and correction by Duplicati.

I read that Borg backup has a "error detection" feature, what a pity that it is not fitted for ACD (or HUBIC).

Regards.